# Tracking Objects from a VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation

Tags: ios, swift, coreml, apple-vision

I am using Vision and a `CoreML` Model whose role is prediction rather than classification or image-to-image processing. I input the `pixelBuffer` and get back a `[VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation]`[1](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vncoremlfeaturevalueobservation).

```
func createCoreMLRequest() -> VNCoreMLRequest? {
    guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: yolo.model.model) else { return nil }
    let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { (finReq, err) in
        if let results = finReq.results as? [VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation] {
            let features = results.compactMap({ (obs) -> MLMultiArray? in
                obs.featureValue.multiArrayValue
            })
            let boundingBoxes = self.yolo.computeBoundingBoxes(features: features)
            guard let prediction = boundingBoxes.first else { return }
            self.observation = VNDetectedObjectObservation(boundingBox: prediction.rect)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.highlightView.frame = prediction.rect
            }
        }
    }
    return request
}
```

I then fetch the `[MLMultiArray]`[2](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/mlmultiarray) from the Observation and feed it to YOLO.swift to compute the bounding boxes. The bounding boxes are an array of predictions. The predictions is a struct containing a rect(boundingBox), className and confidence.

Using the predictions I want to track the objects. So I use Vision and and create a `[VNDetectedObjectObservation]`[3](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vndetectedobjectobservation) with the prediction's boundingBox. Then I create a `[VNTrackObjectRequest]`[4](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vntrackobjectrequest) and pass in the detected observation but the resulting observation always returns the same boundingBox as the initial prediction.

```
func createTrackRequest() -> VNTrackObjectRequest {
    let trackRequest = VNTrackObjectRequest(detectedObjectObservation: self.observation) { (finReq, err) in
         if let results = finReq.results as? [VNDetectedObjectObservation] {
            if let observation = results.first {
                self.observation = observation
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.highlightView.frame = observation.boundingBox
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return trackRequest
}
```

I am not sure why this is happening. Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you running the VNTrackObjectRequest?

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans using `try? VNSequenceRequestHandler().perform([trackRequest], on: pixelBuffer)`

Comment: I suggest looking at some Apple sample code about how to use the tracking APIs, it's a little more tricky than that. For example, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/tracking_the_user_s_face_in_real_time

Comment: Thanks @MatthijsHollemans. The sample helped me resolve the issue I was facing. Any reason why my initial code does not work?